# how to get text after a specific p tag in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

how to get all text after third p tag from this code in BeautifulSoup web scraping.

```
questions = soup.find('div',{'class':'entry-content'})
exp = questions.p[3].text
```

(there is c a way something like this but i cant get it. )
anyone here can help. shall be very thanksfull[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtAwf.png)

Comment: See [ask] a question, and how to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, if that helps:

```
#This will fetch first div with class entry-content.
# In case if that is not the first div then instead use find_all and select the 
# appropriate div with help of indexing.
questions = soup.find('div', class_= 'entry-content')

#This will get all the p tags present in questions.
p_tags = questions.find_all('p')

lst=[]
for tag in p_tags[3:]:
     lst.append(tag.text)

#This will get you the text of the 4th <p> tag.
exp = p_tags[3].text
```

Comment: thanks but it only allows to get the text of the third 'p' tag but I want to get all text including other 'p' tags text that came after the third 'p' tag              I have use `exp = p_tags[3:].text` But I am getting error that             **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'**

Comment: Then you can make use of loops. Iterate through p_tags[3:] and then store the text each time to a new list. I edited my answer, to store the text values of all p tags into a new list.

Answer (score 0):

This `questions = soup.find('div',{'class':'entry-content'})`
Only finds one `p` tag,

you need:

```
questions = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'entry-content'})
```

To find all the `p` tags, then you can use `[3]`